# IllegalStateException In Android

Tags: android, static, view, illegalstateexception

Im having some problems with an IllegalStateException. I have a function that creates removes all the views from a LinearLayout and recreates and re-adds them. One of these TextViews must be static so that it can interface with a custom view I have created. When that TextView is added to the layout for the second time, the program throws the IllegalStateException. After stepping through the program a bit, It seems that the parent LinearLayout has removed the view from its children, but the TextView itself still "thinks" that it has a parent. Here is my code: (Only the important bits)

```
 public static TextView latchingText;
 private LinearLayout layout;

 private void recreateLayout(){
      layout.removeView(latchingText);
      layout.addView(latchingtext);
 }
```

Does anyone have any clue whats going on?

EDIT:Here is the Log:

```
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:2012)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1907)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1864)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1844)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.PhysicsEngine.Diagram.createTraceLayout(Diagram.java:357)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.PhysicsEngine.Diagram.access$3(Diagram.java:173)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.PhysicsEngine.Diagram$2.onClick(Diagram.java:270)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2405)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8813)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-13 09:04:41.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10489):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can Views be static? Please post your logcat for further understanding

Comment: A view reference *can* be `static` but I would avoid doing so unless I had no other choice.  If @Tom C insists on using it in this way, then please read this article on [avoiding memory leaks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: Thanks for the article. The textview is created using the activity's context and so it should not leak memory. My problem is only the illegalstateexception.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the View **must** be static. Are you sure that the *same* "latchingText" View appears in the layout each time? Perhaps you need to find it via getViewById each time through.

Comment: I have added the log cat to the question

Comment: Also, I noticed that your capitalization is inconsistent (`latchingText` vs. `latchingtext`. Is this a transcription error, or do you really have two variables with such similar names?
`layout.removeView(latchingText);
      layout.addView(latchingtext)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log say what you need to do.

```
child.getParent().removeView(child);
```

This should basically work. Check for null, the getParent() might be null...

A short explanation: The layout variable is not static, so it is very possible that the layout variable you use to call `removeView()` is already another one and so it is not working for the child. To prevent that you should try to always access the parent by calling `getParent()` and not only by using a member variable that might already be overridden by a new object.

Comment: Thank you very much. after dealing with the null pointer and the casting it worked perfectly. I don't know why this works differently than layout.removeView(latchingText) though.

Comment: So what is the "child" for his question? Variable "layout" in recreateLayout() or?